# Generating Primary key without set it as key

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework, mvvm

When I create a table in entity framework, i am not set any key in the table. But, when the table created the id field in the table set as key, Why?

```
 public class EntityBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DeletedOn { get; set; }
    public string RefId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4) Entity framework automatically identifies the primary key based on ideal naming like `Id` in your case :-

As detailed in document :-

> Other default conventions supported by EF include the ability to
>   automatically identify primary-key and foreign keys based on common
>   naming patterns (for example: an ID or DinnerID property on the Dinner
>   class will be inferred as the primary key).  EF also includes smart
>   conventions for wiring-up association relationships between models.

For more information :-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx